# npm run watch issue

Tags: laravel, npm

I'm new to laravel, now Im trying to create a project and I want to run the command of `npm run watch` however it gives me error. Looked for answers online but nothing helped.

```
> @ watch C:\Users\ZARI\Desktop\motelproj
> npm run development -- --watch

> @ development C:\Users\ZARI\Desktop\motelproj
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"

One CLI for webpack must be installed. These are recommended choices, delivered as separate packages:
 - webpack-cli (https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli)
   The original webpack full-featured CLI.
We will use "yarn" to install the CLI via "yarn add -D".
Do you want to install 'webpack-cli' (yes/no): yes
Installing 'webpack-cli' (running 'yarn add -D webpack-cli')...
'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
undefined
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Is this in a fresh install Laravel? Have you changed any of the `sass` or `js` files in your `resources` directory or the `webpack.mix.js` yet?

Comment: Not fresh install, and I added some in `sass` and `js`. Nothing was changed in `webpack`

Comment: In there more output before `undefined`? Also, have you run this command before and it's worked fine?

Comment: It didn't work before. There's more, wait let me edit it.

Comment: Done edit @Rwd!

Comment: `'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command`. Do you have `yarn` installed on your system?

Comment: No, do I have to install it? @Rwd

Comment: Judging by the message, yes, however, you might not need to if you don't want to. Please can you edited your question and add the contents of your `package.json` file.